# nodejs sqlite3 как удалить данные в базе из цикла

Tags: javascript, node.js, sqlite3

требуется удалить данные в базы из цикла

```
 db.all("SELECT * FROM iterations", function (err, rows) {
    rows.forEach(function (row) {
        if(date_now > row.date_work && date_now > row.date_sleep) {
            db.run(`DELETE FROM iterations WHERE date_work = ${row.date_work}`)
        }
    })
})
```

Данные не удаляются, если вынести за пределы  db.all(), то тогда работает как надо и данные удаляются, как решить проблему и удалять в цикле?

Comment: Почему бы не собрать все условия WHERE и удалить данные одним запросом?)

Comment: Потому что условие зависит от row

Comment: `delete from iterations where date_work < :date_now and date_sleep < :date_now`

Comment: @АндрейПтицев это делается одним запросом. ``DELETE FROM iterations WHERE ${date_now} > date_work AND ${date_now} > date_sleep``. Примерно так, разве нет?

Comment: Раз уж на то пошло: `DELETE FROM iterations WHERE date_work in (select date_work from iterations where date_work < :date_now and date_sleep < :date_now)`.. А вообще, вы сумасшедшие люди, что запускаете скрипты через api.. sql инъекции никто не отменял ещё